# Expresiones Regulares en Visual Basic.net

Tags: vb.net, regex, webforms

Estoy realizando expresiones regulares en un formulario de registro usando Web forms. Me gustaría saber si esta bien hecho porque al momento de registrar no pasa nada.

**Este es mi código de la expresión regular:**

```
Dim expre_regul As String = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+@(hotmail|gmail)[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/"

        Dim r As Regex = New Regex(expre_regul)

        If Not r.IsMatch(txtCorreo.Text) Then
            Return
        End If
```

**Este es el código completo de mi botón "Registrar"**

```
Protected Sub btnRegistrar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegistrar.Click

    Try

        Dim clRegistrar As New SIMULADOR_LOG.clsExamenLOG
        Dim User As New SIMULADOR_ENT.clsUsuarioSim
        With User
            .dni_user = txtDNI.Text
            .ape_pat_user = txtApellidoPaterno.Text
            .ape_mat_user = txtApellidoMaterno.Text
            .nombre_user = txtNombres.Text
            .direccion_user = txtDireccion.Text
            .celular_user = txtCelular.Text
            .correo_user = txtCorreo.Text
            .dept_user = cmbDepartamento.Text
            .prov_user = cmbProvincia.Text
            .dist_user = cmbDistrito.Text
            .fech_nacimiento = txtFechaNacimiento.Text
        End With

        Dim expre_regul As String = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+@(hotmail|gmail)[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/"

        Dim r As Regex = New Regex(expre_regul)

        If Not r.IsMatch(txtCorreo.Text) Then
            Return
        End If

        Dim mensajeLog As String = clRegistrar.RegistrarUsuario(User)

        Dim Mensaje As String = "<script type=""text/javascript"">" &
                                "Message('El sistema dice: " & mensajeLog & "')</script>"

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "msg", Mensaje)

        Response.Redirect("SimuladorExamen.aspx")

    Catch

        'ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(Page), "alerta", "alert('Ingrese un valor válido');", True)

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: En lugar de `Return`, ¿considerarías cambiarlo para que evalúe la expresión y colocar así `If r.IsMatch(txtCorreo.Text) Then <tu lógica>  End If`? o ¿el `Return` para qué es necesario aquí?. te recomiendo [edit] tu pregunta agregando ejemplos de correos que estás usando.

Comment: Hola @Mauricio Arias Olave, te explico, lo que pasa es que cuando le doy al botón "Registrar" no pasa nada, yo ya lo he validado en javascript usando jquery usando alerts, pero al momento de que sale el alert y le doy aceptar, el flujo continua, osea el código dentro del "Protected Sub btnRegistrar_Click" se sigue ejecutando y eso no quiero. Por eso solo me quedo realizar nuevamente las expresiones regulares pero en visual basic.net.

Comment: Gian Franco, deberías [edit] la pregunta con el código javascript. Por lo que entiendo, desde el webform validas con javascript y en algún punto se dispara el evento `btnRegistrar_Click`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.net no usa delimitadores en la expresión regular. Eliminá los `/` del principio y del final.

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+@(hotmail|gmail)[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$"
```

Answer (score -1):

Usa https://regex101.com/ para probar tu expresión regular.

Por ejemplo, yo usé:

> mail@**mail**.com

Y la validación me dice que "mail@**mail**.com" **NO** coincide con el patrón.

Pero, si uso:

> mail@**hotmail**.com

La validación me dice que "mail@**hotmail**.com" sí coincide con el patrón.

Comment: El problema es que regex101 no usa el motor de .net